# real number to integer points game

Tags: game-theory

[image]

Not sure what this question is about, and looking for ideas about a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  let me take Jack's place and you take Colin's place.  If I play $0.95$, what do you play?  How about $9.95?$  What does that tell you?  If I play $0.51, 0.49, 0.26?$  Does this help?

Added:  We only care about the fractional part of Jack's number, so we will assume the number is in $[0,1)$.  We will also assume that you round toward an integer if possible, so $0.05$ rounds to $0$ and $0.95$ rounds to $1$, though this is not important because you can move off the exact number by a small amount.

If Jack picks a number in $[0,0.05]$ or $[0.95,1)$ Colin will choose $1$ because they round to an integer.  If Jack picks a number in $[0.475,0.525]$ Colin will choose $2$.  If Jack picks a number in $[\frac 13-\frac 1{60},\frac 13+\frac 1{60}]$ or $[\frac 23-\frac 1{60},\frac 23+\frac 1{60}]$ Colin will choose $3$.  Keep note of what of the interval has been covered as you go up through the choices for Colin.  When the last bit of the interval is covered, you have the answer.  $19$ seems reasonable because each number by itself covers a length of $0.1$ but there are areas of overlap.

Comment: Is repeating same real number allowed and is there a limit of times they can play? - the problem doesn't seem to make much sense but it's from a national level math contest in the last year

Comment: The question is really about only one play of the game.  It is harder than I originally thought.  If I play $0.95$ you play $1$ because it is already within $0.1$ of an integer.  My point about $9.95$ is you don't care about the integer part of a number, because you still play $1$.  If I play $0.51$ or $0.49$ you play $2$ because those bring us within $[0.95,1.05]$  Does that help?

Comment: Then why not picking a real number such as 10^(-6), which will make Jack get 10^6 points? or 10^(-1000) if ok. The provided answer is 19, not sure how to get that

Comment: Because $10^{-6}$ rounds to $ 0$, so Colin will choose $1$